# TextView keeps moveing when text is added?

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, adt

I have developed an app that calculates a score. When text is appended to the TextView it moves slightly from its original location.

how can I stop it from moving and let it grow vertically downwards?

[image: side by side comparison]

Comment: We need to see your layout XML & Java code to help you find the problem...

Comment: Please see above, I added the xml and java codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just figured it out.

I was adding unnecessary lines by "\n" in my java code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change this

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to

```
android:gravity="top"
```

in your textviews.

Comment: Try to remove the layout_align etc.. options for the textview into the .xml file and see what happens

Comment: Thank you Vittorio, it was because of line addition in my java code. Thanks buddy.